# postgres copy with row delimiter

Tags: postgresql

I have a table foo with column bar

```
foo
---
bar
```

I use Postgres's Copy command
    COPY (select * from  foo) TO 'complete_file_path' WITH Delimiter ',' CSV HEADER

Now, how to pass a custom row delimiter? Example

```
row delimiter = _a_\n
```

I require the follow output in my file

```
bar_a_
somevalue_a_
somevalue_a_
somevalue_a_
```

I am not sure how to do this using the copy command.

Answer (score 3):

Postgres [COPY TO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) has no option to specify an alternative row delimiter.  You could always do some post processing with sed or language of your choice to turn newlines into `"_a_\n"`. or you could do some string concatenation in your select:

```
COPY (select bar || '_a_' as bar from foo)
  TO 'complete_file_path'
  WITH Delimiter ',' FORMAT CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to use sed/awk.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but wonder, why?  If you're worried about embedded new-lines in what is getting extracted, then I'd recommend switching to the `TEXT` format, which will escape any embedded newlines as the two characters "\n" leaving any *actual* new line characters as being unambiguous record separators.

One down-side of `TEXT` is that you don't get the headers :-(

One way around *that* is to CSV extract with `HEADERS` and  `LIMIT 0` (to *just* get the headers), and then do the `TEXT` extract.  Clunky, but an option.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html for details of the `TEXT` format.